# POST to a JSON file using AJAX and only javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

I am trying to post to a local son file which is saved within the same folder as all my code. I have done the following:

```
function test(){
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();   // new HttpRequest instance 
xmlhttp.open("POST", "data/people.json");
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;");
xmlhttp.send(JSON.stringify({name:"John Rambo"}));
}
```

The above function is run when I click on a button in my html:

```
<input type="button" onclick="test()">
```

And my son file looks like this:

```
 {
  "People": [
  {"name": "tony stark"},
  {"name": "iron man"}
  ]
}
```

but I keep getting a 404 not found error. is there anything that I am doing wrong?
Apologies if I missed something out if you require more information to answer the question please let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That error means there's no `data/people.json` file. You can't use AJAX to create a file on the server, you need a script on the server to process the request.

Comment: The `data/people.json` is the file your REQUESTING. Ideally you in your POST you should request something like a PHP file that can receive the POSTed data and then create the file you want from the data.

Comment: Actually, you might be able to use AJAX to create a file, if your server is configured to allow `PUT` requests.

Comment: @JonathanM is it possible to post some data to a local json file? I can read the local json file. Is there anyway to post or enter data to it.

Comment: No, it's not possible to post data to a file. POST requires a script to process the data.

Answer (score 0):

Since I can't comment because I don't have enough reputation, if you want to enter data into your json file, the best thing you can do is:

- Get the file and turn the JSON into an Object.
- Once you have the object, push more data into it.
- Afterwards, save the file / replace it with the object containing the new and the old information.

This is just a simple work around, but as other said in comments, you can't "POST" data into the file unless you do what I've just said.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Double check the URL end point.
Should be server script file which is made to accept the request.

And try sending is Key=Value pair.

```
xmlhttp.send("name=John Rambo");
```